# StanfordCoreNlp with MapReduce(Error: GC overhead limit exceeded)

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, stanford-nlp

I have a text file containing a set of document IDs and document contents, delimited by "::". Here's an example

```
139::This is a sentence in document 139. This is another sentence.
140::This is a sentence in document 140. This is another sentence.
```

I want to do some named entity recognition with those sentences using StanfordCoreNLP. This has been working fine with a conventional java program. Now I want to do the same using MapReduce. I am trying to load the StanfordCoreNLP classifiers in the setup() method of my mapper, and the map() method does the named entity tagging, as follows:

```
public class NerMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>{

StanfordCoreNLP pipeline;

@Override
protected void setup(Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setup(context);
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, parse, dcoref, relation");
    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
}

@Override
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value,
        Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) throws IOException,
        InterruptedException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] input = value.toString().split("::");
    List<DataTuple> dataTuples = new ArrayList<DataTuple>();
    Annotation annotation = new Annotation(input[1]);
    pipeline.annotate(annotation);
    List<CoreMap> sentences = annotation.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    for(CoreMap sentence : sentences){
        //extract named entities
        //write <documentID>::<the named entity itself>::<the named entity tag>
    }
}
}
```

On running the job, it fails with the error "GC overhead limit exceeded". I have tried different heap sizes by doing `export HADOOP_OPTS="-Xmx892m"` before running the job, and I include the StanfordCoreNLP dependencies using the `-libjars` option of `hadoop jar` command. The input documents typically consist of just 4-5 normal-sized sentences. I understand that the problem lies in initialization of the classifiers in setup() method, but I have not been able to figure out what exactly is wrong. I would really appreciate any help here!

I'm using hadoop 2.6.0, Stanford CoreNLP 3.4.1 and java 1.7.